# Problems linking boost-log static on FreeBSD 11.4 works on 12.2

Tags: c++, cmake, freebsd, boost-log

I have used boost log to make a customized sink. I have been using it on Windows for another project and now I used a slimmed down variant of it for another project which shall (must) run on FreeBSD 11.4.
I have switched to cmake build in order to support building on Windows/Linux/FreeBSD. I can compile and link static and dynamic on Windows, Linux (Centos 8) and FreeBSD 12.2. However on FreeBSD 11.2 I get linking problems when using static linking.

I use boost 1.74 and I have compiled from source using bootstrap and b2 for clang compiler.
I use -DBOOST_ROOT=[boost 1.74 root] as a cmake argument to specify the boost root.

I made a minimal cmake project which uses my sink in order to rule out any other problems.
When trying the static linking I get the following errors:

```
usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/logtest.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/logtest.dir/logtest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/logtest.dir/applogger.cpp.o -o logtest  /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_log.a /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_log_setup.a /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.a /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_thread.a /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.a -lpthread /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_regex.a /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_chrono.a /home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_atomic.a

/home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_log_setup.a(default_formatter_factory.o): In function `void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::type_dispatcher::callback_base::trampoline<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::anonymous::default_formatter<char>::visitor, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process> >(void*, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process> const&)':
default_formatter_factory.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix15type_dispatcher13callback_base10trampolineINS1_3aux9anonymous17default_formatterIcE7visitorENS5_2idINS5_7processEEEEEvPvRKT0_[_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix15type_dispatcher13callback_base10trampolineINS1_3aux9anonymous17default_formatterIcE7visitorENS5_2idINS5_7processEEEEEvPvRKT0_]+0xd): undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process> const&)'
/home/user/dev/boost/lib/libboost_log_setup.a(default_formatter_factory.o): In function `void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::type_dispatcher::callback_base::trampoline<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::anonymous::default_formatter<wchar_t>::visitor, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process> >(void*, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process> const&)':
default_formatter_factory.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix15type_dispatcher13callback_base10trampolineINS1_3aux9anonymous17default_formatterIwE7visitorENS5_2idINS5_7processEEEEEvPvRKT0_[_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix15type_dispatcher13callback_base10trampolineINS1_3aux9anonymous17default_formatterIwE7visitorENS5_2idINS5_7processEEEEEvPvRKT0_]+0x11): undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >& boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::operator<< <wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process> const&)'
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

CMakeLists.txt content:

```
project(logtest)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED
COMPONENTS
log
log_setup
)

add_executable(logtest)
target_sources(logtest PRIVATE logtest.cpp applogger.h applogger.cpp)

target_link_libraries(logtest PRIVATE Boost::log)

# Dynamic linking works
#target_compile_definitions(logtest PRIVATE BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK=1)
```

applogger.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/log/attributes/mutable_constant.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/manipulators/add_value.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


namespace appLogger
{
const uint32_t no_log      = 0;
const uint32_t console_log = 1;
const uint32_t use_ram_log = 2;
}  // namespace AppLogger


namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(
   sysLogger,
   boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level>)


class AppLogger
{
public:
   /// Init with default info level logging
   static void init(
      uint32_t logSink                          = appLogger::no_log,
      boost::log::trivial::severity_level level = boost::log::trivial::error);

   /// Disable logging
   static void disable();

   // Flush log
   static void flushLogs();

   // Convert file path to only the filename
   static std::string path_to_filename(std::string path)
   {
      return path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);
   }

   // Set Log level
   static void setLogLevel(int32_t level);
};

#define LOG_LOG_LOCATION(LOGGER, LEVEL, ARG)                     \
   BOOST_LOG_SEV(LOGGER, boost::log::trivial::LEVEL)             \
      << boost::log::add_value("Line", std::to_string(__LINE__)) \
      << boost::log::add_value("File", AppLogger::path_to_filename(__FILE__)) << ARG


// System Log macros.
// TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL
#define LOG_TRACE(ARG) LOG_LOG_LOCATION(sysLogger::get(), trace, ARG);
#define LOG_DEBUG(ARG) LOG_LOG_LOCATION(sysLogger::get(), debug, ARG);
#define LOG_INFO(ARG) LOG_LOG_LOCATION(sysLogger::get(), info, ARG);
#define LOG_WARN(ARG) LOG_LOG_LOCATION(sysLogger::get(), warning, ARG);
#define LOG_ERROR(ARG) LOG_LOG_LOCATION(sysLogger::get(), error, ARG);
#define LOG_FATAL(ARG) LOG_LOG_LOCATION(sysLogger::get(), fatal, ARG);
```

applogger.cpp:

```
//  appLogger.cpp

#include "applogger.h"

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/settings.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(
   sysLogger,
   boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level>)


BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_timestamp, "TimeStamp", boost::log::attributes::timer::value_type)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_severity, "Severity", boost::log::trivial::severity_level)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_file, "File", std::string)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_line, "Line", std::string)


void AppLogger::init(
   uint32_t logSink,
   boost::log::trivial::severity_level level)
{
   boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory<boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char>(
      "Severity");
   
   if(logSink == appLogger::console_log)
   {
      boost::log::add_console_log(
         std::clog,
         boost::log::keywords::format =
            "[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%] %File%(%Line%): %Message%");
   }

   // boost::log::add_common_attributes();
   boost::log::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", boost::log::attributes::timer());
   boost::log::core::get()->add_global_attribute(
      "ThreadID", boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id());


   boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= level);

   // Indicate start of logging
   LOG_INFO("Log Start");
}

void AppLogger::disable()
{
   boost::log::core::get()->set_logging_enabled(false);
}

void AppLogger::flushLogs()
{
   boost::log::core::get()->flush();
}

void AppLogger::setLogLevel(int32_t level)
{
   boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= level);
}
```

logtest.cpp (application):

```
#include "applogger.h"
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

 
int main()
{
    boost::log::trivial::severity_level logLevel = boost::log::trivial::debug;
    AppLogger::init(appLogger::console_log, logLevel);

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "Hello Logger"; 

    LOG_DEBUG("Starting Client!")
    
    return 0;
 }
```

Any ideas how to solve this or troubleshoot further?

/Thanks

Comment: You may be affected by https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20638. Check if `-lboost_log_setup` goes before `-lboost_log` in the linker command line. Avoid using `Boost::log` in `target_link_libraries` and instead list `boost_log_setup` and `boost_log` libraries there, in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! I can confirm that this was the problem. Manually linking and change order of the libs worked.

To make this work automatically with Cmake I added: 

set(_Boost_LOG_SETUP_DEPENDENCIES log)

to my CMakeLists.txt which fixes the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrey suggested: It's a problem in CMake FindBoost which is confused about dependencies.

**Fix:**
*Add in CMakeLists.txt:
set(_Boost_LOG_SETUP_DEPENDENCIES log)*

I still don't know why it works without this fix in FreeBSD 12.2. It uses the same version of CMake as 11.4 (3.18.3).